# Why does sdk expression need to be by the end of the bash_profile file? Is it really necessary considering the "wrong" position and normal behavior?

Tags: bash, zsh, macos

I have recently started using macOS (OSX is the old name for the same thing), after multiple years of Linux.

In macOS Monterey, `.zshrc` is the default. This is my `.zsh`:

```bash
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Yesterday, I decided to change it to `bash`, since it is the shell that I am used to. Thus, I did so by pointing and clicking on preferences.

This my `.bash_profile`:

```bash
#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

As you see above, there is a comment stating that the expression on SDKMAN should be at the end of the file for the program to work.

The funny thing is that I only noticed this after **normally** using `sdk` on terminal.

Why is this necessary? Considering that the program has worked as expected, is it really necessary on `bash_profile`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to ask the developers who wrote that code to be sure, but my guess is it doesn't need to be the absolute last thing in the `~/.profile`, it just needs to be after other variable definitions and setup has happened.

The command `source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"` will read the script `sdkman-init.sh` and run any commands in it, including variable definitions, in the current shell. So if that script assumes certain things to be defined, it will fail if it is sourced before they are defined.

For example, that script might need some directories to be in your `PATH` so if you source it before setting up your `PATH`, it won't work. That is most likely why the developers want you to have it at the end. Now, in your example, the only things after the `sdkman-init.sh` command are about `nvm` so if sdkman doesn't depend on nvm in any way, it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm essentially repeating parts of terdon's answer here)*

Developers ask for their actions to be placed at the end of a shell startup file like `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` because they don't want other actions already in the file to override their actions.

Since the developer of software *X* does not know what other actions are in your shell startup files, the safest advice they can give to you is to add their actions last.